# How is galvanic isolation established in an SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, isolation

I can understand how an isolation transformer can establish isolation but since **SOME** SMPS supplies don't have transformers and they have rectifiers instead I wonder how the AC and DC ends are isolated.

**Edit:** [Here is an SMPS with no galvanic isolation.](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/7516739/)

[Here is the datasheet which says there is no galvanic isolation.](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1072/0900766b810728dc.pdf)

How is that possible?

I'm asking because people here all agreed SMPS has small transformers which isolates the input and output power.

Comment: It's simple: Without a transformer there **can** be no isolation.  *but since SMPS supplies dont have transformers and they have rectifiers instead;* It doesn't work like that. You're comparing a **mains transformer** to rectifiers. These are completely different things ! A mains transformer lower the AC voltage and provides isolation, a rectifier makes DC from AC.

Comment: how bout here bridgre rectififer convertes mains ac to dc isnt it?: http://www.thinkisemi.com/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/php/fckeditor/upload/201210/block_diagram_of_the_SMPS-01(1).jpg

Comment: Yes, the same happens in the picture in Andy's answer. The way these supplies work cannot be compared to a solution using a mains transformer. They provide similar functions (lower voltage, isolation) but achieve that in different ways and for a different price.

Comment: @FakeMoustache  Btw, is the galvanic isolation's only purpose or advantage is safety?

Comment: Isolation is not only for safety, it can also help to separate and isolate sensitive parts of measurement equipment. Isolation prevents unexpected currents to flow. It makes design easier and safer as isolates parts can interfere less with eachother. Take 2 lab supplies of 30 V, 1A. You can connect them in series and have 60 V, 1A. This is possible because they're isolated.

Comment: Here an SMPS with no galvanic isolation: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/7516739/ Here is the datasheet(says there is no galvanic isolation): http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1072/0900766b810728dc.pdf How is that possible?

Comment: @user16307 "SMPS" is a broad term. It includes both isolated converters (forward, flyback) and non-isolated converters (buck, boost, buck-boost).

Comment: @AdamHaun I do not understand since people here wrote me that SMPS have small transformers which establish isolation. Some even wants to close this question because they I guess believe all SMPS have transformers and the question is nonsense. Im kind of confused.

Comment: Do some SMPS which do not have isolation do not also have transformers?? Is that because they cannot isolate?

Comment: @user16307 You phrased your question poorly. It sounded like you were saying that no SMPS has a transformer, which is wrong. People are answering that part. You should do some reading about the different SMPS topologies.

Comment: @AdamHaun I edited my question. So how are ones which do not have trsnsformers isolated?

Comment: @user16307 They aren't.

Comment: @AdamHaun Does that mean the impedance between input power's Neutral and output power's DC grounds have low impedance?

Comment: Yes. But non-isolated converters normally take low-voltage DC as input. AC to DC converters normally have to isolate the rectified high-voltage DC for safety reasons, so they use an isolated converter topology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure they have transformers: -

[image]

[image]

The transformer looks different to a regular AC type but it's still the largest single component on the PCB but a whole lot smaller than it would be for 50/60 Hz operation. The transformer is the big yellow taped thing in front of the heat sink at the back/left.

SMPSs also use opto-isolators for feeding back a measure of the output voltage so that it can be regulated. This is another significant isolation feature thus, output and input remain galvanically isolated to several kV and are therefore "safe".

Comment: But SMPS are small. How can that transformer in your diagram be small? Rectified AC is PWM switched and then fed to the transformer in your diagram. Is it possible to provide waveforms corresponding the diagram above?

Comment: Because the frequency of the switching converter is much higher, the transformer can be much smaller.

Comment: The trick is that the "oldfashioned" mains transformer needs to work at 50 or 60 Hz (the mains AC frequency) , for that it needs to be bulky. In an SMPS we can operate it at 100 kHz or more (note the switching transistor), this allows the transformer to be much cheaper, smaller and more efficient.

Comment: A transformer's size (for a given application and power transfer) is roughly inversely proportional to operating frequency. As an SMPS might operate at 100 kHz it's operating at about two thousand times higher than a conventional AC transformer hence it's tiny in comparison. It's all about avoidance of saturation.

Comment: so are you saying that when the frequency is increased the transofrmer(which is an inductor) size decreases. okay but what is making the frequency increase? in the above diagram what i see is that a rectified mains AC is PWM switched. How does that section increase 50Hz up to 100kHz?

Comment: The transformer is a transformer and some types of SMPS (fly back notably) it's sometimes referred to as a coupled inductor. The AC is rectified and smoothed producing a reasonable DC. The switching is done at anything from 10 kHz to 1MHz - there is an oscillator that is capable of being pulse width modulated. The PWM driver in my top picture runs at this higher frequency (nominally 100 kHz).

Comment: @Andyaka Sounds like an operation of a VFD up to the transformer

Comment: @Andyaka Here an SMPS with no galvanic isolation: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/7516739/ Here is the datasheet(says there is no galvanic isolation): http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1072/0900766b810728dc.pdf How is that possible?

Comment: It uses a "protective earth" system for ensuring safety and the output will likely be bonded to that protective earth internally. You have to provide that annoying 3rd wire to power it! However, that is beside the point because it WILL use a transformer.

Comment: @Andyaka Some says here it " You can have unisolated switching supplies (they are usually called DC-DC converters rather than SMPS): they have and inductor instead of the transformer." If there would be a transformer wouldnt  it be galvanic isolated already?

Comment: Transformers lend themselves to give galvanic isolation. DC to DC converters are *usually* galvanically isolated because they tend to use fly-back topologies (i.e. a transformer).

Comment: @Andyaka so you are saying it has transformer but the earth causes a bridge between neutral and the DC ground?

Comment: I'm not making any claim - I'm speculating but certainly there will be **NO** electrical connection between neutral and earth. That would be wrong and unsafe. The Earth likely connects to the secondary side thus, if the transformer fails, hot AC is shunted through to earth and a fuse breaks or a breaker trips. I don't want to speculate any more about the device you linked because the data sheet is really poor.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this is a common misconception, among people who have studied DC-DC converters only. The truth is that transformers are often used in AC-DC SMPS, specifically when isolation is required.

The difference is that the transformer takes the place of the inductor of a regular DC-DC converter, and energy is transferred magnetically to one or many secondary coils.

Feedback is often achieved with an opto-isolator, but there are other methods of feedback as well.

Typically a first stage will be a non-isolated power factor correction stage, which passes the 400V DC to the regulator with transformer isolation.

Answer (score 4):

SMPS do have transformers. They are not quite the same as the 50Hz transformers you find in linear power supplies, because they work at a much higher frequency, (like ~100kHz), but they have one. Look inside a PC power supply:

[image: supply]

The transformer is the block with the yellow tape and the writing on it, between the heat sinks.

Any AC-input supply also have rectifiers (usually as a bridge). They are placed before the transformer for SMPS, or after the transformer for a linear supply, but they don't replace the transformer.

Comment: @Andyaka Here an SMPS with no galvanic isolation: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/7516739/ Here is the datasheet(says there is no galvanic isolation): http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1072/0900766b810728dc.pdf How is that possible?

Comment: I edited my question. Apperantly some SMPS do not have transformers. So how re they isolated?

Comment: @user16307 I believe that is a DC-DC SMPS/power supply supervisor. It looks at the output from two different supplies, and if one fails the other takes over, via this module. They simply added more regulation to it. And, as others have pointed out, many DC-DC SMPS are not isolated.

Comment: DC TO DC?? http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/7516739/ It says input is AC here

Comment: Well, it's simple: the SMPS that do **not** have transformers are **not** galvanically isolated. You can have unisolated switching supplies (they are usually called DC-DC converters rather than SMPS): they have and inductor instead of the transformer. But in this case, it's simply not isolated.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question, yes, you can have a non-isolated AC-DC SMPS that uses an inductor instead of a transformer. Generally you want isolation for safety, but for some applications isolation isn't required.

Some of the confusion is because the product page linked to in the question is all messed up.
 Although the page says the product is is a SMPS, the title is wrong. The page shows an inrush current limiter that takes AC input and outputs AC, limited to 10A. It doesn't provide galvanic isolation since it's kind of a surge protector for a SMPS, not a complete SMPS. The page describes the product as a "redundancy module", but that is a totally different product that can be added to an SMPS.

Comment: Please don't make product recommendations on this site

Comment: I'm not recommending any products. My intent is to explain that the original poster's link doesn't describe an SMPS. But I'll edit my answer to take out the links if they are objectionable.

Comment: Its not the worst thing to do, its just not within the guidelines. Better to provide links to a wiki or try and put the information in the post.

Answer (score 0):

> I can understand how an isolation transformer can establish isolation; but since SOME SMPS supplies dont have transformers and they have rectifiers instead; I wonder how the AC and DC ends are isolated.

Simple: **they aren't**.